# Find the remainder when $49! ÷ 48$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the remainder .
When $49! ÷ 48$ 
I know the answer is zero.

But I don't know ..how we reached to answer ..??

For instance I know $4!$ When divided by $3$ we got the remainder $0$ ..so if we got bigger numbers how we are suppose to solve them ?

Comment: 49! = 49 * 48 *.... so it is a multiple of 48 and the remainder is zero

Comment: Please write the last few factors, in the expression defining $49!$...

Comment: Um... $49! = 49*48*47*.....*3*2*1$ so $\frac{49!}{48} = 49*47*....*3*2*1$.

Comment: The remainder of $n!$ divided by $m$ where $n \ge m$ has to always be $0$ because $m$ must always be a factor of $n!$.

Comment: $49!$ has $48$ as a factor, so the remainder is $0$...

Comment: Look at all these people writing answers in comments (I think four and a half is a new record, at least for me). Please consider making actual answer posts for your answers, as that is exactly what answer posts are for.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't meant to be the remainder when $48!$ is divided by $49$?

Comment: Brian tung ..I m pretty sure !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $49!$ is  multiple of $48$ so when you divide it by $48$ there is no remainder.